# Tor's Control Port could not be Reached?

Tags: whonix

I recently installed the newest Whonix and after finishing installation received the error:

> Tor Boostrap Result: Tor's Control Port could not be reached!

Troubleshooting:

- Confirm that Whonix-Gateway is running
- Run `whonixcheck` on Whonix-Gateway and confirm success.
- If you're running multiple Whonix-Workstations simultaneously, confirm that separate IP address are configured
- Rerun `whonixcheck` here.

  (Technical information:)
  (Code: 255)
  (tor_bootstrap_timeoit_type: none)
  (tor_bootstrap_status: Socket error: [Errno 113] No route to host)
  (check_socks_port_open_test: 7)
  (Tor Circut: not established)

I tried all the troubleshooting tips and nothing seemed to be a problem. My Whonix Gateway tested fine. What else could be the problem?

Comment: Googling "tor's control port could not be reached" throws up a couple of Whonix-specific threads - have a look at those if you haven't. The "no route to host" error could indicate a complete lack of connectivity to the outside world.

Comment: Guy's if you having the problem with tor connection in workstation[CODE:255] it's only because you are using your WIFI connection.ALL you goota do is:-
1. USE LAN[It's Required or your tor connection in workstation won't work]
2. Get Latest VirtualBox.
3. IMPORT both ova files of Workstation and Gateway.
4. RUN both files together in VirtualBox. voila! your code 255 problem is resolved.

Comment: I am a long-time whonix user and this just started happening to me for no apparent reason. Could it be the latest updates to the gateway? That's the only thing that changed that I noticed. I'm on KVM in Linux. Workstation says "Tor's control port could not be reached!"